# Send a non-serializable parameter to a keyword

Tags: python, robotframework

I was trying to pass a web driver element as a parameter to a keyword and got the exeption in the execution log:

```
[ ERROR ] Calling listener method 'start_keyword' of listener '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/contrib/testrunner/TestRunnerAgent.py' failed: TypeError: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7f686eb02390> is not JSON serializable
[ ERROR ] Calling listener method 'end_keyword' of listener '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robotide/contrib/testrunner/TestRunnerAgent.py' failed: TypeError: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x7f686eb02390> is not JSON serializable
```

Tests still pass, so this doesn't affect the result, but seeing this in a log is not nice. Besides, I don't understand, why it works if all keywords argument are serialized before passing them to actual Python code, and this one is not serializable.

**Question**: can I pass non-serializable arguments in RobotFramework? For now I'm trying to send not an element, but a named tuple of the element identifiers.

The code I use:

```
class ElementKeywords(object):
    def has_text(self, element):
        return bool(self.get_element_property(element, 'text'))

    def wait_until_result(self, timeout, poll_period, func, *args):
        time_spent = 0
        timeout = convert_time(timeout)
        poll_period = convert_time(poll_period)
        result = False
        thrown_exception = None
        while True:
            try:
                result = func(*args)
                thrown_exception = None
            except Exception as exc:
                result = False
                thrown_exception = exc
            if result or poll_period > timeout or time_spent > timeout:
                break
            time_spent += poll_period
            time.sleep(poll_period)
        if result:
            return True
        if thrown_exception:
            raise thrown_exception

        msg = 'Failed to receive positive result from {func} in {timeout} ' \
              'seconds'.format(func=func.__name__, timeout=str(timeout))
        raise TimeoutError(msg)
```

Test case code:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup        Web Setup
Test Teardown     Web Teardown
Resource          web_resources.txt

*** Test Cases ***
Check Index
    [Tags]    US123456
    Web Login
    Clean Redis
    ${job_id}=    Create Pool
    Web Refresh
    ${data_pool_element}=    Get Element By Xpath    //div[@id="progress-pool"]/div[1]
    Wait Until Result    20    1    Has Text    ${data_pool_element}
    Validate Pool    ${job_id}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in your code. You can pass non-serializable objects. The RIDE test runner appears to have a bug. Try running your testcase from a command prompt and the problem should go away.

Comment: With pybot the issue is gone. So we decided to keep passing elements. Thanks!